# make customizable keyboard shortcuts chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I am making a chrome extension with a keyboard shortcut to open a `pop-up` and the code below works fine. It's just that I want the user to be able to specify the keyboard shortcut to open the `browser action` via the `options.html` page. How might I go about this?

- Note: I am not open to using `Jquery`, `other 3rd party plugins`, or `content-scripts`.

I would prefer to use a `dropdown` w/ the allowed shortcut keys (`Ctrl+Shift+Alt`, `Ctrl+Shift`, `Ctrl+Alt`, `Ctrl`, & `Alt`) mixed with a `textbox` only allowing one key to be entered.

That last part is a sub-question, but the main thing here is:

### How Can I make Customizable Keyboard shortcuts within options page?

Manifest.json:

```
|  ...  |
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "png/Icon-128.png",
  "default_title": "Gamez.io",  
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
},
"permissions": [
   "activeTab",
    "tabs"
],
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "windows": "Alt+X",
      "mac": "Alt+X",
      "chromeos": "Alt+X",
      "linux": "Alt+X"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Chrome doesn't have an API to set the hotkey. Users can do it manually on chrome://extensions/shortcuts page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way... Well kind of...

Steps:

1. Create a `content.js` file and list it in your `manifest`.
2. Then add the following code to your `content.js` file:

> content.js:

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 69) {
    window.alert('You pressed \'e\' !');
  }
};
```

Then see [Here](https://medium.com/@melwinalm/crcreating-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascripteating-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript-763ca19beb9e) on how to make custom `keyboard-shortcuts` using `JS`.

3. Use `JSON` Files and `chrome.setlocalstorage`(something along those lines [still working on it] ) to save the users input from `options.html`.

My current Question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472371/how-to-open-browser-action-from-content-js-is-it-even-possible) How the heck do I trigger the Browser_Action!?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean/ideal way to customize shortcuts thru an extension since those are set  thru the manifest and not alterable programmatically. However the shortcuts you described in your manifest can be manually modified by the user in the chrome://extensions page.