# How to open Browser_Action from content.js? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-pages, browser-action

I am working on a chrome extension that allows users to open the `browser_action` by
pressing a keystroke that ***THEY*** have assigned from the `options-page`.

I would like to use `document.onkeyup = function(){` **`Chrome.runtime.openPopup();`** `};`
or something along those lines... I know that this *Particular* Extension API
(`runtime.`**`openPopup`**) only functions for *`mozilla firefox`*. I am building this extension
for **`Chrome` & `Opera`** so this is not an option for me.

How might I go about this? Would it be through adding `chrome.commands` API to
the `manifest` file; then modifying that file from `options.html`/`options.js` and reloading the extension? I've looked all 
over for a way to do the method explained above and it doesn't seem
like that's possible.

Yes, Yes I know that `Chrome` has a built in method for customizing chrome extension
keyboard shortcuts, but *like I said* I want the **user** to be able to specify the
shortcut from the `options.html` page & I'm developing this extension for `Opera`
too. So that won't really work...

> Any solutions?

I've tried `Content.js`--`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`
& `Popup.js`--`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addeEventListener(function() {self.focus();});`

Comment: Not possible in stable Chrome. Open a new small window instead or insert an iframe into the current page with your UI page declared in web_accessible_resources in manifest.json

Comment: Well Darn... That sucks. Will the Iframe Have Access to chrome.executescript API?

Comment: Yes, the iframe can access everything any other extension page can. And in addition to that you can use chrome.tabs.getCurrent inside the iframe to get the web page tab object, which is pretty convenient.